# validation of password with ()-=_+

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

I am not able to validate passord with ()-=_+ , i.e it should `accept` these special characters but its not working when i use the regular expression as

```
`validates_format_of :password,  :with => /^[A-Za-z0-9. ! @ # $ % ^ & * ( ) _ - + = ]*\z/`
```

its only excepting till * but not `accepting` ()-=_+ in ruby on rails.

Comment: Why are you validating passwords?

Comment: There are few things worse than having a complex (and thus relatively secure) password rejected for being too complex (and thus too secure).

Answer (score 10):

Those characters need to be escaped with a `\`

But I would seriously recommend that you *do not* validate passwords like this! What is the point in *restricting* what users can choose for their passwords? You are artificially reducing the pool of characters for them to choose from, which in turn makes brute-force attacks easier.

Enforcing user names to be ASCII a-z, 0-9 is one thing, but you should certainly not restrict passwords to such a small subset of characters.

Comment: +1 for stepping back and seeing the broader picture. Why are we restricting passwords?

Answer (score 1):

The `-` at least is going to cause problems, think: `[A-Z]`.
The `^` might be causing problems: does `[A-Z^Q]` mean all uppercase letter except Q in your regex flavor? (If so, everything after it would appear to not be there...)

Also: Zero length passwords are valid?

Answer (score 0):

validates_format_of :password,  :with => /^[A-Za-z0-9. ! @ # $ % ^ & * ( ) _ - + = ]*\z/

This worked.